# Как правильно использовать оператор "&" в части перечисления нескольких элементов из списка?

Tags: java, if, логические-выражения

Как правильно использовать оператор "&" в части перечисления нескольких элементов из списка?

Либо какой способ лучше выбрать, чтобы код заработал?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Checkyourexp {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Введите опыт торговли на финансовых рынках от 0 до 99 лет: ");
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int traderExperience = Integer.parseInt(user_input.next());

        String mrating;
        System.out.print("Выберите финансовый инструмент из списка: валюта, акции, облигации, фьючерсы, опционы, криптовалюты, NFT");
        mrating = user_input.next();
        
        if ((traderExperience == 0) || (mrating.equalsIgnoreCase("акции")) || (mrating.equalsIgnoreCase("фьючерсы")) || (mrating.equalsIgnoreCase("опционы"))
                ||(mrating.equalsIgnoreCase("криптовалюты")) || (mrating.equalsIgnoreCase("NFT")))
        {
            System.out.print("Вы не опытный трейдер, Вам нужны советы, обратите внимание на облигации либо попробуйте начать с торговли на валютных рынках");

        }

        else if (traderExperience ==1) || mrating.equalsIgnoreCase("опционы") || mrating.equalsIgnoreCase("криптовалюты") || mrating.equalsIgnoreCase("NFT")) {
            System.out.print(" Вы начинающий трейдер, но мы не рекомендуем вам криптовалюты, опционы либо NFT ");
        }

        else if ((traderExperience >= 2) && mrating.equalsIgnoreCase("NFT")) {
            System.out.print("У Вас хорошие навыки, но лучше попробуйте попрактиковаться ещё минимум год, и вернуться к теме NFT");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Вы уже достаточно опытны, чтобы самостоятельно принимать решение по торговле тем или иным финансовым инструментом");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `&`  или всё же `&&` ?? А может имело в виду `||` ?

Comment: А как по-вашему может выполниться условие _одновременного_ равенства `mrating == " криптовалюты " & mrating=="NFT" & mrating=="фьючерсы" & mrating=="акции"`?

Comment: Вы используете побитовые операторы сравнения. Вам нужны(скорее всего) логические.  и &&   или  ||

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замечания по коду:

- `&` - это побитовый оператор И; в данном случае следует использовать *логический* оператор `&&`
- Для проверки, содержит ли `mrating` *одно из многих* допустимых значений следует использовать оператор логическое ИЛИ `||` -- переменная `mrating` не может одновременно быть равна двум и более разным строкам.
- Поскольку строки являются объектами, их сравнение следует выполнять при помощи методов `String::equals`/`String::equalsIgnoreCase`, а не оператора `==`, который будет сравнивать ссылки на строки, а не их значения
- Так как для пользовательского ввода используется `Scanner::next`, то введённые слова не будут содержать пробелов, как в случае `" криптовалюты "`
- Условия `if (num_age >= 1 ...) if (num_age >= 2 ...)` могут выполниться два раза, вероятно между ними должен быть оператор `else`.
- Вместо проверки условий `if (mrating.equalsIgnoreCase(t1) || mrating.equalsIgnoreCase(t1) ...)`, можно создать множество допустимых значений `Set<String> m1 = Set.of("опционы", "криптовалюты", "NFT", "фьючерсы", "акции")` и т.п., тогда можно использовать метод `Set::contains`: `if (m1.contains(mrating.toLowerCase()))`
- название переменной `user_age` всё-таки обозначает *возраст* пользователя, а не стаж трейдера `traderExperience`, также следует обратить внимание на соглашение об именах переменных/классов, принятое в Джаве, в частности, что названия переменных/методов записываются в `camelCase`.

Полностью исправленный код *не приводится*, работу над указанными ошибками следует проделать самостоятельно.

Comment: Благодарю за столь подробны ответ, очень много понятного стало. Внес, изменения, но по какой-то причине блоки else if(2,3 условие) и else не выполняются, какие меры нужно принять?

Comment: У вас компилятор должен показывать сообщения о неправильно расставленных скобках

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!

Comment: Ответ был крайне полезен, спасибо! Но если я ставлю "Ответ полезен", вылетает сообщение о том, что не делается в моем случае подъем рейтинга("Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.").

Comment: Галочку (что решение принято) можно ставить и без рейтинга, для голосования нужен рейтинг.

Comment: Ещё раз, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю к ответу и к коментам выше.
Оператор & можно использовать , если все операнды типа boolean, иначе это уже  побитовая операция, а && - это укороченное AND которое используется только с boolean. И зачем нужен Integer.parseInt если Сканер на то и Сканер , что у него есть методы парсинга :

1. next (); считывает ввод до пробела
2. nextLine (); всю стрроку до \n и переходит на следующую
3. nextInt ();
4. nextDouble ();